# Android activity method to make display flash white for warning notification

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to get the android activity to flash as a warning to the user (Whole screen). To make it flash I have inserted an ImageView into the activity which is the size of the display and white, which will rotate its visibility from visible to gone. I have looked into creating an external thread but I later found out that external threads cannot alter UI components. I need to pause the thread between flash changes which means I wouldn't be able to put it on the main UI thread. How would I implement something like this?

I have included some of my code below:

**XML**

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/alertScreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/white" />
```

**Main.java**

```
    public static boolean flashOn = false;
    public static boolean endFlash = false;
    public static Context context;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.aircraft_main);
        AircraftMain.context = getApplicationContext();

        flash = (Button) findViewById(R.id.flashTest);
        flash.setOnClickListener(flashBtnOnClickListener);
    }

    View.OnClickListener flashBtnOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
                public void run(){
                    AlertFlash alert = new AlertFlash(3);
                    alert.run();

                    ImageView v = findViewById(R.id.alertScreen);

                    while (endFlash != true) {
                        if(flashOn = true) {
                            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        } else {
                            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    };
```

**AlertFlash.java**

```
public class AlertFlash implements Runnable {

    public static volatile int flashes;
    boolean suspendFlag, end;

    public AlertFlash (int flashNo) {
        flashes = flashNo * 2;
        suspendFlag = false;
        end = false;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i<=flashes; i++) {

            if (suspendFlag = false) {
                AircraftMain.flashOn = true;
                suspendFlag = true;
            }
            else {
                AircraftMain.flashOn = false;
                suspendFlag = false;
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        end = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Activity.runOnUiThread()`, you can modify UI elements from a background thread.

Here's how I'd go about it in your situation. Inside Main.java, I'd start by creating a simple method to modify the visibility of a passed-in view, specifically on the UI thread:

```
private void setViewVisibility(final View view, final int visibility) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            view.setVisibility(visibility);
        }
    });
}
```

Then I'd change the `while` loop to the following:

```
while (endFlash != true) {
    if(flashOn = true) {
        setViewVisibility(v, View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        setViewVisibility(v, View.GONE);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** to prevent problems with the while loop, we can bypass it entirely by passing in the `activity` and `view` when creating the `AlertFlash` object. See below.

```
public class AlertFlash implements Runnable {

    public static volatile int flashes;
    boolean suspendFlag, end;

    private Activity activity;
    private View view;

    public AlertFlash (int flashNo, Activity activity, View view) {
        flashes = flashNo * 2;
        suspendFlag = false;
        end = false;

        this.activity = activity;
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i<=flashes; i++) {

            if (suspendFlag = false) {
                AircraftMain.flashOn = true;
                suspendFlag = true;
            }
            else {
                AircraftMain.flashOn = false;
                suspendFlag = false;
            }

            final int visibility = AircraftMain.flashOn ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE;
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    view.setVisibility(visibility);
                }
            });

            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        end = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. When implementing that it only seems to be taking the first result "flash on" even though it's running the full for loop. Should I move the while loop elsewhere?

Comment: I can't say for sure by what I'm looking at here. Where does `endFlash` get set to true?

Comment: I changed that. On AlertFlash.java I have changed the end condition to `Main.endFlash = true` which alters the stopping condition on the Main.java file. But it seems that it is only executing the while loop after running AlertFlash.java fully. Therefore, it is not running the while loop because the stopping condition has been called. Where could I move the while loop so that it is executed at each iteration of the AlertFlash for loop.

Comment: See my latest edit. Try passing the activity and view directly into the AlertFlash object, then modifying the view's visibility in there. No need for the while loop, in that case.

Comment: There's an error in the alertflash class,  if (suspendFlag = false) {     should be if (!suspendFlag) {